# Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() in Parameterized.class junit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit4

I want to create a test case and use the same test case several times but with different data, as shown below.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest extends TestCase {
    private MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();

    @Parameterized.Parameter(0)
    public float expectedResult;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
    public float firstNum;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(2)
    public float secondNum;

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: testAdd {0} = ({1}+{2})")
    public static Collection<Object[]> testData(){

        Object[][] data = new Object[][]{ {6,2,4}, {7,4,3}};

        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() throws InterruptedException {
        float result = firstNum + secondNum;
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result, .1);
    }
}
```

And this is the end result.

[image]

The test did generate the test cases but the test cases suppose to be passed and not failed. The error was

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

I tried all the solution that is available but it still shows the same message.

Comment: `private MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();` you can not do this. Activities are supposed to be created by the framework for you. That way they will have a proper Looper attached. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.

Comment: Even if i remove private MainActivity ma = new MainActivity(); I still got the same error.